# JQuery fades not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I'm new to JQuery and can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't behaving properly. As the content in my "content" div changes, I want it to fade in and out. I created a generic "load" function to do this:

```
function loadPage(page, callback) {
    if(current_doc != page) {
        current_doc = page;
        $("#content").fadeOut(400, function() {
            $("#content").load(current_doc, function() {
                $("#content").hide().fadeIn(400, function() {
                    if(typeof(callback) == 'function'){ callback(); }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Is there some sort of glaring mistake that I'm missing?

Thanks.

P.S. - This code works fine in Firefox.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: why hide() of you are allready in fadeOut()

Comment: @Brewal 1.11.1, but I tried using 1.6.4 as well based on the solution to an older, but similar problem.

Comment: What does "not behaving properly" mean? Anyway, my psychic powers tell me that if you replace `.hide()` with `.promise()` you will get the expected behavior.

Comment: Well, I gess you will have to provide a demo

Comment: @Jon The window hangs for a moment, then immediately switches to the new content. No animation is shown whatsoever. It simply loads slower than if I just removed the fades entirely. While I don't doubt your psychic powers, replacing hide with promise just stopped the content from loading altogether...

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check in IE, in Internet Options > Advanced, under Multimedia should be a checkbox that says "play animations in webpages". Ensure that is checked.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but don't have the rep to comment on main question.

Comment: Well, I undo my downvote but this is still not an answer

Comment: The dv is mine, and I gave it because that IE setting has absolutely no relation to jQuery animations. I have no idea where you got that from, but obviously you did not try it even once (you would have seen it does nothing) and yet you still offer it as a solution. And of course you don't even know that the OP is using IE.

Comment: Title says "in ie9". This has happened to me in the past, was just offering a possible solution. Unfortunately, new users cannot add comments on questions.

Comment: @nismonster This is why I undone my dv. This is nonsens to me

Comment: @nismonster: My apologies for that. But again, "animations" in that context does not refer to jQuery.

Comment: Yep, animations as referenced in those settings means animated Gifs and things of that ilk. jQuery animations work by manipulating the DOM at frequent intervals during the transition. I'd normally also downvote as this is not the right answer. It's not meant personally, it's just how this site works. I'm skipping in this case as it will help you get to comment-level rep quicker

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not entirely sure why, placing the content div inside another div and fading that instead seems to have done the trick. I would think that that would have been giving me issues only if "content" itself were being deleted, but that isn't the case from my code. Oh well.